# Amsbook \part error

Tags: errors, packages, parts, amsbook, pdfsync

In my tex file I have

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,caption,fancyhdr,multirow,booktabs,lscape,pbox}
\usepackage{amssymb,nomencl,todonotes,framed,booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,graphicx,graphics,epstopdf,amsxtra,amscd,color,latexsym,mathrsfs,bbding,rotating,mathdots,mathrsfs,hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfsync}

\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb   {1.47in}  % left margin
        {0.7in}  % top margin
        {1.1in}  % right margin it was {1.1in}
        {0.6in}  % bottom margin
        {5pt}  % head height -- it was {15pt}
        {0.2in}  % head sep
        {13pt}  % foot height %WAS 9pt
        {0.4in}  % foot sep

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}%number the table as Table.c.s.t//  c=chapter, s=section,t=table
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}

\begin{document} 

\author{My name} 
\title{PhD. Thesis} 
\date{\today} 

\include{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\include{abstract}


\newpage ~
\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage


\tableofcontents

 \mainmatter



\part{Background}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I work on MacOS. There were no problems or errors with my set up till February (last time I compiled my tex file). In this week I upgraded my OS to Maverick and I had to install again MacTeX + TeXShop. Now I have TeXShop Version 3.18 (3.18). I don't remember which version I had few months ago.

Compiling for the first time my file, called "Thesis.tex" today I get the following error:

```
) [10]
./Thesis.tex:304: Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   #
l.304 \part{Background}

?
```

I have figured out why \part{..} is not liked. If you want you can delete this thread or keep it here for future references.

I have done several attempts:

1. As it is --> the error as above is detected
2. Deleting \part{..} --> It works with no errors
3. Avoid to use \usepackage{pdfsync} -->  Everything works fine!!!

So apparently the package *pdfsync* is clashing with the amsbook command \part.

Comment: PLease put something real inside the MWE, not just *stuff*, much more likely you will get help. Plus the simplest `amsbook` document possible containing a `\part` compiles just fine, so the *stuff* matters. Plus there is no option called `two-sided`

Comment: Please be so kind and strip down your code even more, we don't have files as `intro/introduction1` and we miss your packages to get a better picture of what's really going on.

Comment: the fact that you're using `\fancyhead` indicates that a special package is being used.  it's possible that this package isn't compatible with `amsbook`; most packages that modify headers and toc formats have problems.  so more detail is needed.

Comment: `pdfsync` is an obsolete package; never use it. Also `vmargin` is known to create problems, it's better to use `geometry`.

Comment: I used *vmargin* here only because it was easier to get all the parameters required from the school office. Usually I do use *geometry*. Actually I don't know why there is *pdfsync*, probably I copy pasted an old code.

Comment: @rafforaffo Please, don't add `SOLVED` to the title, but rather add an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to `\usepackage{pdfsync}`; the `pdfsync` package was a first attempt for providing inverse search from the PDF file to the TeX file, but it has several problems and, above all, it has been made obsolete by the SyncTeX technology now used by default in all TeX engines, provided the `-synctex=1` option is enabled, which is by default with TeXShop.

Remove the call to the package and all will work well.

By the way, `vmargin` is incompatible with several packages, so it's better either to use the native `amsbook` methods or `geometry`.